# Generate and concatenate videos from images with ffmpeg in single command

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, mp4

My goal is to generate a video from images. Let's say I have 2 images `1.png` and `2.png`.

I can do

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 1.png -t 3 1.mp4
```

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 2.png -t 5 2.mp4
```

to create a 3 second video from the first image and 5 second video from the second image.

Then, I merge the two videos using

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -I 2.mp4 -filter_complex "concat" final.mp4
```

to create my final 8 second video.

This process seems extremely inefficient, and I feel I do not have to use all this processing power+disk reading/writing to create 2 intermediary video files when I only want the one final video.

Is there a way to execute this entire process in one ffmpeg command (efficiently)?

Answer (score 1):

The most versatile way is to use the [`concat` filter](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#filter).

Perhaps an easy way out assuming that all the durations are nice numbers (e.g., integer seconds like you have in your example), then you can acctually use [`concat` muxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer) and **repeat** files to occupy the desired time span.

Using your example,

`concat.txt` (in the same directory as the images)

```
ffconcat version 1.0
# repeated 3 times for 3 seconds
file capture_1.jpg
file capture_1.jpg
file capture_1.jpg
# repeated 5 times for 5 seconds
file capture_2.jpg
file capture_2.jpg
file capture_2.jpg
file capture_2.jpg
file capture_2.jpg
```

FFmpeg command with input rate of 1 frame/second:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -r 1 -i concat.txt
```

Obviously, this will get pretty ugly quickly but it does work.

If you are to script generating the concat file, you might as well go the filter route imo.

Comment: That made my day!

Answer (score 0):

If your images are smoothly and continuously numbered i.e. (1.png, 2.png, 3.png) not (1.png 02.png 4.png) then run

`ffmpeg -i %d.png -vf "setpts='eq(N\,0)*0+eq(N\,1)*3+eq(N\,2)*8',tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=2" out.mp4`

In setpts, each image is assigned a timestamp that sets when it *starts* showing, so the image timestamp is equal to the cumulative duration of all earlier images. The tpad sets the duration of the final image. Add `-r X` just before out.mp4 to set a fps of X.